# jQuery interfering with other jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a particularly heavy jQuery site which has lots of animations.

There is this script which controls the background clouds (6 of them):

```
function moveClouds(e, s, d) {
$(e).css('left', '-20%');
    var wait = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(e).animate ({
            right: '120%'
        }, s, 'linear', function() {
        moveClouds(e, s, d);
    });
},d);
}

if(!Modernizr.cssanimations) {
var clouds = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$.each(clouds, function() {
    var e = $('.cloud-' + this);
    moveClouds(e, e.data('speed'), e.data('delay'));
});
}
```

There is this one that makes balloons hover and also other elements (12 of them):

```
function runIt(element, hoverAmount) {
         element.animate({top: '+=' + hoverAmount}, 1000);
         element.animate({top: '-=' + hoverAmount}, 1000, function() {
             runIt(element, hoverAmount);
         });
     }

     $('.balloon').each(function() {
         var hoverAmount = 15 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
         //console.log(hoverAmount);
         runIt($(this), hoverAmount);
     });
```

and others that move objects, fade stuff in and out etc..

The problem is now with the more content that gets added and images the clouds and the balloons are now jerky and no longer smooth. I'm pretty new to jQuery so my question is:

Is there a way to make them not conflict? use less resources and run smoothly?

Comment: [**Greensock GSAP**](https://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/)

Comment: You could look into use CSS animations rather than using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments above here state, it's better not to use jQuery for lots of complex simultaneous animations.

Greensock uses CSS transforms to move objects around. You can also program your own CSS transforms. These use hardware acceleration and will animate your objects much faster and smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I think you'll find that [GSAP (GreenSock Animation Platform)](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) works **much** better. It's literally up to ***20x faster*** than jQuery. Plus I'd recommend animating x/y instead of top/left/right since transforms don't affect document flow and can therefore be rendered much faster. Also, try adding `force3D:true` to your GSAP animations which will put the elements onto their own compositor layer(s).

With GSAP, you can loop/yoyo animations, nest them, `seek()` to a certain spot, `reverse()`, alter the `timeScale`, and lots more. jQuery just wasn't built for serious animation.

Oh, and I'd avoid doing lots of `setTimeout()` calls if you can. Those can get costly when they're stacked up. GSAP has a `delayedCall()` method that ties into its single central ticker and is more efficient under pressure.

You may also want to read this article: http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

If you need help with GSAP, there are dedicated forums at http://forums.greensock.com

Happy tweening!